# How to build the Android sample projects using Ant? build.xml does not exist

Tags: android, ant, build, android-build

I believe I've followed the instructions in the Android SDK, and I'm now trying to build the sample LunarLander (random one picked)

```
$ cd samples/android-11/LunarLander
$ ant debug
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I believe all PATHs are setup correctly. 
I've done this before in an older Android SDK release and I know I didn't encounter this error, so I'm pretty confused as to what's wrong.

Oh, one more piece of info -- I have only installed the 3.0 platform package, so I'm not sure if that is an error or not.

Comment: Do you have a `build.xml` in `samples/android-11/LunarLander` directory?

Comment: just: AndroidManifest.xml, overriding the xml build file with that gave an error as well

Comment: stop making it hard for yourself and use eclipse

Comment: i use xcode, just a personal preference.  the project i start will be an ndk one, with most coding being C++.. breakpoints will be inputted via gdb commands directly, as from i can tell theres no integration instructions provided to link ndk-gdb with eclipse from what i've read

Comment: I tried all the possible answers but no way till i found this [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16707758/1752899

Comment: I tried all the possible answers but no way till i found this [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16707758/1752899

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You need to execute this command:

```
android update project --target <your build target> --path <path to LunarLander example>
```

which will create the needed build.xml within the example directory, then the `ant debug` command should work.

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject).

*You can use `android list targets` to choose what build target to use for your project.

Comment: Using just "target 1" isn't usually a good solution. Execute `android list targets` and select the appropriate target id for the project to build.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `android update project -p <path>`, where <path> is the path of the project (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15718940/1103747).  This form is just a bit more concise and easy to remember.

Comment: The android command is localized on $ANDROID_HOME/tools/. For libraries there are other commands. Check it here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject

Comment: `android update` was removed in SDK tools 26.0.1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955478/895245

Answer (score 5):

**`android updated project` was remove in SDK tools 26.0.1**

Don't use Ant. It is not properly supported anymore. For now, just use Android Studio GUI and create Gradle projects manually.

`android update project` was finally [removed in SDK tools 26.0.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906942/android-update-project-path-target-android-25-on-ubuntu-16-04) after a long deprecation period, and fails for example wth:

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command "update project -p ./bloom -t android-23"
```

So now I don't know a good way to create a project from the CLI without Android Studio. The best workaround I have so far is to create a template project with Android studio, and he copy it around with a helper script as described at: [How to create android project with gradle from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801042/how-to-create-android-project-with-gradle-from-command-line/46994747#46994747)

Also I haven't managed to easily import an existing Ant project to Gradle: [Doing an Ant Build on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618395/doing-an-ant-build-on-android-studio) so I just copy the sources around for now.

**Before 26.0.1**

When starting a new project you can use:

```
android create project \
    --target 1 \
    --name MyName \
    --path . \
    --activity MyActivity \
    --package com.yourdomain.yourproject
```

which creates the `build.xml` automatically.

Those demo projects contain only `gradlew` files: I wish Google could use only one of Ant or Gradle for everything.

Comment: The gradle wrapper should do all things for you. Just `./gradlew :appDebug` and you're good!

Answer (score -6):

Please install at ubuntu openjdk-7-jdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

on Windows, try find find openjdk.

Comment: Nope, ant runs so Java is installed