# How to create build.xml for an Android project?

Tags: android, ant, android-build

I've been trying to run simple programs that I obtained directly from the Source Code download for the book 'Beginning Android 4'.  However, I have lots of problems with the build.xml files (see previous questions, which are unanswered).  My latest is, which comes from the a simple Label demo program:

```
# ant debug
Buildfile: /home/me/src/ANDROID/MyProjects/Label/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "debug" does not exist in the project "LabelDemo".
```

I then checked with other working build.xml files and as fasr as I can tell, grepping thru the text of the file, 'debug' doesn't exist there either.  But they work.

So, I obviously must be creating build.xml files incorrectly.  What is the correct way to create the build file for an Android project (from the command-line).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Run **`android update project -p ...`**, where the `...` is the path to the project. This will create or update the `build.xml` and related command-line build files. This assumes that your SDK's `tools/` directory in your `PATH`; otherwise, you will need to fully-qualify the path to the **`android`** command.

Comment: Cool!  This worked.  It also 'solved' my other problems with 'taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found'.

Comment: android update project -p . --target android-19

Comment: Google decided for you, that you cannot use android command line tool anymore. Therefore this command does not work anymore. Thank you Google :(