# Using Ant for building Android Studio Projects

Tags: android, android-studio, ant

My company uses ant + jenkins to automate our build.

Recently I've upgraded a few of our existing Android projects from eclipse to Android Studio. Has anybody have any idea on how to use ant instead of gradle for building Android Studio projects?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618395/doing-an-ant-build-on-android-studio It's good practice to search online before asking a question. If you still have issues describe what you're doing and what's not working.

Comment: I recommend you to change your build tool from Ant to gradle. it is faster and more Extensible.