# Android build failing with build.xml:479: SDK does not have any Build Tools installed

Tags: android

Why does my build fail with this error?

> {android-sdk}/tools/ant/build.xml:479: SDK does not have any Build
>   Tools installed

It started showing up after updating SDK tools to 22

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

http://andrewma.com/2013/05/18/resolving-sdk-does-not-have-any-build-tools-installed-error/

After upgrading my Android SDK to 22, I started running into failed builds with the error message:

> {android-sdk}/tools/ant/build.xml:479: SDK does not have any Build
>   Tools installed

Couldn’t find very much on the web on how to resolve this and eventually I realized that it was because I only updated existing packages. In SDK 22, the platform tools and build tools are split up into their own items in the SDK manager.

Make sure you install the build-tools and platform-tools.

Answer (score 75):

try run

```
android update sdk -u
```

in terminal.

You will see logs like this on your screen

```
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 17
  Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 17
    Stopping ADB server succeeded.
    Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 1799%)
  Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
  Installing Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
    Installed Android SDK Build-tools, revision 1799%)
  Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2
     (71%, 775 KiB/s, 41 seconds left))
```

After Android SDK is successfully updated, make sure Build Tools is installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I installed Build Tools using SDK manager. They look installed, but they aren't. My {SDK}/build-tools folder is simply empty.

I just downloaded sdk from *http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html* and moved *android-4.2.2* folder in my *build-tools* folder.

Comment: If I follow this correctly, you downloaded an html file and moved a platform folder into the build tools. This makes no sense and does not come close to resolving the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have android SDK build-tools installed:

`$ ~/Desktop/android/tools/android`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `.buildozer/android/platform/andoridsdk/tools` and run Android SDK GUI. Install the latest build tools. I just worked around this; I installed buildtools 19.1 and the packaging was done successfully.

Answer (score -1):

For manual build-tools installation, go to: 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Scroll down to <----build-tools----> 
Copy the zip file link (which one depends on your development environment operating system) and paste it in the url box and click search.
Save it somewhere, extract it into the build-tools folder.