# sdk does not have any build tool installed

Tags: android, ant, build, sdk

i have installed all the build tool, but still getting this error please advice.
[image]

[image]

Please advice

Thanks

Amith

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631693/android-build-failing-with-build-xml479-sdk-does-not-have-any-build-tools-inst